# Change event after autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I have a ruby on rails application with an input text field that has an autocomplete mechanism. This mechanism works like this

```
$(function() { if ($('#autocompleting_field').autocomplete) { function.... } });
```

No I want to call a controller action when this field changes

```
jQuery(function($) { $('#autocompleting_field').change(function() { call the controller });
```

Now I have the problem that the controller is called right at the moment that I type in some words in the field but not after I have selected something from the autocomplete mechanism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind your after function with `select` event of autocomplete. Like this:

```
$(function() {
  if (
    $('#autocompleting_field').autocomplete({
      select: function(event, ui){
        //the after function
      }
  }) {
    function....
  }
});
```

Although I'm not sure why you use the `if`

Note: assuming http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ [Events->'select']